# Changing JavaScript alert buttons

Tags: javascript, button

How do you change the words on the buttons in a javascript alert? I am new so the simplest way possible would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Buttons? There is only *one* button inside an alert-box...

Answer (score 6):

You can't.

Instead, you can create a fake dialog in the DOM, using [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Comment: How is this going to block the JS execution?

Comment: It can't.  Therefore, you should not replace the built-in `alert` function, which does.

Comment: I hear you Slaks but nothing was mentioned in the question about this.

Answer (score 3):

not possible, the browser sets that

what you could do is make a fake alert from elements,

Answer (score 0):

You can overriede window.alert and have your own implemenation of it.

```
window.alert = function(msg, options){
     //Create the alert dialog box here using the default options and show the message.
}
```

You dont have to change your code in the application to use it.

Comment: That's not true.  `alert` is a blocking call; there is no way to simulate that.

Comment: You can create a modal dialog which will definitely block the UI on the page.

Comment: But it will return immediately.  `alert` only returns when the user clicks OK.

Comment: You can have an OK button which will unblock the UI only on click of it.

Comment: **But the function will return immediately**, unlike `alert`.

Comment: what do you mean return immediately? Even when you click on javascript alert Ok button it returns immediately. I have implemented this kind of custom alert in 2 of my projects without any issues.

Comment: A custom function will return **before** the user clicks OK – right after the dialog is shown.

Comment: Looks like you have never implemented any modal dialog using javascript.

Comment: It is not possible to make a function that doesn't return until the user clicks a button.  You don't understand what I mean.  For more information, show a demo.

Comment: @Slaks - Check my another answer in which I have given you sample code to create a custom alert.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
    function CustomAlert(msg){
var customAlert = $("#customAlert");
      if(!customAlert.length){
        customAlert = $(document.body).append('<div id="customAlert"><div class="message">Msg></div><div><input class="button"     type="button" value="Ok" /></div></div>').hide();
}
customAlert.find("message").html(msg);

//Code to center the customAlert into view port along with faded background will go here

customAlert.find("input.button").unbind("click").click(function(){ 
 //Hide the customAlert goes here
 customAlert.hide();
});

    }
```

Comment: As I've been trying to explain, **this function will return immediately**, before the user clicks OK.  To understand what I mean, call it twice in a row.

Comment: This function will be returned immediately but by now you displayed the alert message which is a abosolute positioned div container and have also blocked the UI. Unless the user clicks OK it will not unblock.

Comment: **But your code will continue running**.  That is a breaking change, so you should not replace `alert`.

Comment: @Slaks - Which part of code you say will be continously running? I have implemented this in one of my previous projects for my current company which is in production. Anyways you can go ahead with your thoughts thanks.