# how to change the default labels of jquery alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change default button labels "ok" and "cancel" of jquery alert box to "delete" and "trash" can we do that without the use of any custom modal or boxes because i have seen some example around like "stay" and "leave" etc. Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing JavaScript alert buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655945/changing-javascript-alert-buttons)

Comment: Looking for this ?http://devzone.co.in/show-confirmation-box-page-refresh-page-unload-using-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override the appearance of the alert box.  You can, however, create your own using jQuery's [Dialog.](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)